# Swift not showing return type while bridging from Objective C to Swift. How to get the return value?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Swift not showing return type of a function while bridging from Objective C to Swift. What is the problem here and how to get the return value?

```
// Objective C

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test: NSObject

+(BOOL)testName :(NSString*)name challenge:(NSString**)challenge error:(NSError**)error;

@end

// Swift
import Foundation

open class Test : NSObject {

    open class func testName(_ name: String!, challenge: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>!) throws
}
```

[Click on this link to get my scenario's reference snapshot in Xcode assistant editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8uFG.png)

Comment: Please, don't paste code as an image. Paste it as code.

Comment: See for example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664888/fmdb-usage-with-swift-returning-a-boolean: Swift automatically translates Objective-C methods that produce errors into methods that throw an error according to Swift’s native error handling functionality.

Comment: Thanks, @FreeNickname

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR